# Json_normalize gives character by character result

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am currently trying to normalize a json file with pandas and got a problem while working on it.

The json file looks like this :

```
{ "valid": false, 
  "checks": {"bank_check": {"valid": true, "reasons": {}, "last_checked_at": "2019-02-19", "first_checked_at": "2019-02-01"}, 
              "company_check": {"valid": true, "reasons": {}, "last_checked_at": "2019-02-19", "first_checked_at": "2019-02-01"}, 
              "ceo_check": {"valid": true, "reasons": {}, "last_checked_at": "2019-02-19", "first_checked_at": "2019-02-01"}}
```

I am interested in getting the list of checks in a table like this:

```
| bank_check  | company_check | ceo_check|
------------------------------------------
| true        | true          | true     |
```

But when I use json_normalize I get this:

[image: Result of json_normalize character by character]

If I use `works_data=json_normalize(d[1], record_path=['result', 'checks'])` , I get the error `string indices must be integers`.

Did anyone face this before? Or have you got any idea why I get this strange result?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that issue is being raised (note your json in the example is missing a closing `}`). I tried to normalize it myself though and was able to produce your desired output:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

d = { "valid": 'false', 
   "checks": {"bank_check": {"valid": 'true', "reasons": {}, "last_checked_at": "2019-02-19", "first_checked_at": "2019-02-01"}, 
              "company_check": {"valid": 'true', "reasons": {}, "last_checked_at": "2019-02-19", "first_checked_at": "2019-02-01"}, 
              "ceo_check": {"valid": 'true', "reasons": {}, "last_checked_at": "2019-02-19", "first_checked_at": "2019-02-01"}}}



df = json_normalize(d['checks'])
cols = [ col for col in list(df.columns) if 'valid' in col ]   

works_data = df[cols]
```

**Output:**

```
print (works_data)
  bank_check.valid ceo_check.valid company_check.valid
0             true            true                true
```

Comment: Thank you I finally find what I was doing wrong. I was in fact doing json_normalize not on the json but on a little dataframe with the json and an index 0. So I had to get rid of the index to make it work. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: oh ok. ya that makes sense. I was a little confused as to how `d[1], record_path=['result', 'checks']` was giving you some output. But glad you worked it out